# Importing data from Careers destroys the preferred displayed sites under the avatar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, developer-story, cv-import

To reproduce:

- Add sites to your developer story which are not in your Careers profile
- Import your data
- Observe that the sites that you've selected are no longer selected.

Answer (score 7):

This is intentional, but I agree it's not very clear. Importing the CV will overwrite any existing data in the story. Manual import is a beta-only thing; it's not worth to add any sort of content merge functionality for that.

Once you've imported, it says "This will remove your story and recreate it based on your CV" next to the (now re-)import link, but we should add something similar to the initial link.